# source activate not work for conda, possible issue with PATH, using mac

Tags: bash, anaconda, conda

I have just installed conda and i cannot active my python.

the line of code i am trying is

```
source activate py27
```

but i get the error

```
bash: activate: No such file or directory
```

the output from

```
conda info --envs
```

is

```
my_root                  /Users/home/.conda/envs/my_root
py27                     /Users/home/.conda/envs/py27
py28                     /Users/home/.conda/envs/py28
snpy                     /Users/home/.conda/envs/snpy
root                  *  /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
```

So i know they are here. but when i type `which activate` there is no result. 
What do i need to do?

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of conda, `source activate` is replaced with a simple `conda activate`.

Comment: when i type conda activate, the output says "Did you mean "source activate py27" ?"